# Trouble with jquery lavalamp

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

For some reason my background color shoots back to the leftmost link no matter what link I click on. Anyone know how to get it to stay on the clicked link?

css

```
#lamp {
float:left;
margin:25px 0px 0px 90px;
clear: both;
}

.lavaLamp {
position: relative;
height: 29px; width: 400px;
background: #000000 no-repeat top;
background-image:url('http://wildfire-restaurant.com/images/lampback.png');
padding: 15px; margin: 10px 0;
overflow: hidden;
float:left;
}
    /* Force the list to flow horizontally */
    .lavaLamp li {
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
    }
        /* Represents the background of the highlighted menu-item. */
        .lavaLamp li.back {
            background:  no-repeat right -30px;
            width: 9px; height: 30px;
            z-index: 8;
            position: absolute;
        }
            .lavaLamp li.back .left {
                background: #BD5108 no-repeat top left;
                height: 30px;
                margin-right: 9px;
            }
        /* Styles for each menu-item. */
        .lavaLamp li a {
            position: relative; overflow: hidden;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font: bold 14px arial;
            color: #fff; outline: none;
            text-align: center;
            height: 30px; top: 7px;
            z-index: 10; letter-spacing: 0;
            float: left; display: block;
            margin: auto 10px;
        }
```

jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { $(".lavaLamp").lavaLamp({ fx: "backout", speed: 700 })});
</script>
```

site http://wildfire-restaurant.com/

Comment: I think displaying only relevant css/code would help this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the class `current` to the current `li` on the sub pages. The lavalamp plugin  runs this bit of code:

```
curr = $("li.current", this)[0] || $($li[0]).addClass("current")[0];
```

Which selects the `li` with a class of `current` or the first item. You can add this class on the server prior to sending to the client, no need to do it in javascript.

**Update**

This is what the HTML would look like for the navigation, when your browser is at the '/menu/' page. Notice how the `li` with the link to `Menu` has the `class="current"`:

```
<ul class="lavaLamp">
    <li><a href="http://wildfire-restaurant.com/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="http://wildfire-restaurant.com/menu/">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://wildfire-restaurant.com/events/">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://wildfire-restaurant.com/friends/">Friends</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://wildfire-restaurant.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
    <li><div class="left"></div></li>
</ul>
```

On the **EVENTS** page, the `li` with the link to `Events` would have the class:

```
<li class="current"><a href="http://wildfire-restaurant.com/events/">Events</a></li>
```

etc.

Comment: Could you possibly rephrase that for a noob?

Comment: Gotcha, this makes sense. The only problem is that I'm powering this site with wordpress.

Comment: so do I add this to the script?
curr = $("li.current", this)[0] || $($li[0]).addClass("current")[0];

Comment: @Davey, edit your question to remove the huge block of CSS, leave the jQuery part, and then at the bottom put "EDIT" and then paste in the part of your WordPress template that writes out the navigation menu. I will take a look and try to help you out with adding the "current" class.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/lavalamp2) extension....

try setting 'autoreturn' to true.

otherwise there is likely an option to set which link the background returns to.  In which case you will have to set it onClick().

Try reading the documentation.

Also, posting more info about the extension you'r using would be beneficial.  This isn't a CSS problem.