# jquery lavalamp focus

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trouble with jquery lavalamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997544/trouble-with-jquery-lavalamp)

For some reason my background color shoots back to the leftmost link no matter what link I click on. Anyone know how to get it to stay on the clicked link?

css

```
#lamp {
float:left;
margin:25px 0px 0px 90px;
clear: both;
}

.lavaLamp {
position: relative;
height: 29px; width: 400px;
background: #000000 no-repeat top;
background-image:url('http://wildfire-restaurant.com/images/lampback.png');
padding: 15px; margin: 10px 0;
overflow: hidden;
float:left;
}
    /* Force the list to flow horizontally */
    .lavaLamp li {
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
    }
        /* Represents the background of the highlighted menu-item. */
        .lavaLamp li.back {
            background:  no-repeat right -30px;
            width: 9px; height: 30px;
            z-index: 8;
            position: absolute;
        }
            .lavaLamp li.back .left {
                background: #BD5108 no-repeat top left;
                height: 30px;
                margin-right: 9px;
            }
        /* Styles for each menu-item. */
        .lavaLamp li a {
            position: relative; overflow: hidden;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font: bold 14px arial;
            color: #fff; outline: none;
            text-align: center;
            height: 30px; top: 7px;
            z-index: 10; letter-spacing: 0;
            float: left; display: block;
            margin: auto 10px;
        }
```

jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { $(".lavaLamp").lavaLamp({ fx: "backout", speed: 700 })});
</script>
```

site http://wildfire-restaurant.com/

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice in one day: #1997544

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your pages has the home page link set as `class='current'`  If you want to have each page have it's menu entry highlighted then you need to either:

A) Update your WordPress code so different pages generate different navigation links (in other words, so that each page has its menu entry `<li>` set to `class='current'`)

An example:  On your home page you have:

```
<ul>
<li class='current'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Menu</a></li> ... etc.
```

Your menu page code needs to look like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li class='current'><a href='#'>Menu</a></li> ... etc.
```

Looking at the Wordpress Documentation it looks like your best be to make use of WordPress' built-in [**Conditional Tag**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) functionality.

This is what [Doug Neiner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997544/trouble-with-jquery-lavalamp/1997596#1997596) was trying to suggest you do.

B) Use javascript to check the url of the page and then update your navigation links based on the URL.

**A** is ***far*** more robust than **B**, and is therefore the option that I would recommend.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with choice a, I am pretty new to this.

Comment: Do you have access to the WordPress template that you are using?

Comment: I do. If you are saying change all the classes for all <li> in the menu to current I tried that and it did not work.

Comment: Davey, you can't change them all to `class='current'` because if you do that, lavalamp defaults to selecting the first element in your `<ul>`.  What you need to do is write out a different menu for each of your pages.

Comment: What is a good way to approach this when everything is static except the content box? The menu list is in my page.php

Comment: Cool, I will read through this article and see what I can figure out. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: So something like this?

<?php 
is_front_page()
<li class="current"><a href="http://wildfire-restaurant.com/">Home</a></li>
?>

Comment: @Davey, you are getting the idea ... you will want to only do it for the ` class='current'` though, otherwise the home page link will only be written out on the home page.

Comment: @Davey ... I'm glad I could be of service. If it was a help, an upvote or an accepted for this answer would be appreciated. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some way to tell the lavalamp what link to set the currently selected item to.

The example code has href="#" so it's probably keeping it's state in some javascript object when clicked.  When you click one of your links the previous pages state is gone.